# Convert array to singly linked list

Tags: c

I have more experience with linked lists after gaining practice and support from SO, given my last few questions. Essentially, I am now following an algorithm that will convert an array to a singly linked list.

```
Algorithm: CONVERT (A, N, HEAD)
1. Set HEAD = NULL
2. Repeat steps 3 to 8 while N ≠ -1
3. Allocated memory for NEW node
4. IF NEW = NULL then Print: “Memory not Available” and Return
5. Set NEW→DATA = A[N-1]
6. Set NEW→LINK = HEAD
7. Set HEAD = NEW
8. Set N = N - 1
[End of loop]
9. Return
```

I have attempted creating the code for this, however, after printing out the node carrying the data, I get a bunch of `zeros`. I know that with an array, if I assign a large size to the array and do not fill all values in, then these are assigned 0. However, this is not the case for my example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int DATA;
    struct node* LINK;
} node;

void convert(int A[], int N, node* head){
    head = NULL;
    while(N != -1){
        node* new;
        new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new == NULL){
            printf("Memory not available");
            return;
        }
        printf("%i", new->DATA);
        new->DATA = A[N-1];
        new->LINK = head;
        head = new;
        N--;
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    node* former;
    former = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    convert(arr, size, former);
    return 0;
}
```

Would print out the following:

```
00000000000%
```

How do I convert the array values to the singly linked list, what might I be missing?

Comment: `printf("%i", new->DATA);` should be after `new->DATA = A[N-1];`, you are printing uninitialized values currently.

Comment: well, you totally lose that head pointer with `head = NULL;`

Comment: also, you dont't free the allocated memory

Comment: @theemee Ah I see, I have updated my script to free the memory. No, I am not inverting it, however, it seems to invert the array. Why might it be doing this?

Comment: You should return `head` from `convert` and replace `former = malloc(...)` with `former = convert(...)`

Comment: To get rid of the `%`, print a `'\n'` at the end of code.

Comment: Algorithm has `Set NEW→DATA = A[N-1]`, even when `N== 0`.  Algorithm is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You don't receive the created list head pointer back to main.
2. You print the data before you assign it and the printing will be inverted if you do during the creation of the list.
3. You don't free the allocated memory and create memory leaks.

Here is how to fix it:

1. Return the created list head pointer from the convert function.
2. Write a separate function for printing the list.
3. Write a function for freeing the memory of the list.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int DATA;
    struct node *LINK;
} node;

node *convert(int A[], int N);
void printList(node *head);
void freeList(node *head);

node *convert(int A[], int N)
{
    node *head = NULL;
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory not available");
            freeList(head); // free already allocated memory
            return NULL;
        }
        new->DATA = A[i];
        new->LINK = head;
        head = new;
    }
    return head; // return the head pointer
}

void printList(node *head)
{
    node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", current->DATA);
        current = current->LINK;
    }
}

void freeList(node *head)
{
    node *current = head;
    node *next = NULL;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->LINK;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    node *former = convert(arr, size);
    printList(former);
    freeList(former);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cast not needed in `(node *)malloc(sizeof(node))`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica some compilers and compiler options won't compile without it. It doesn't hurt

Comment: All compliant C compilers compile `node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));`.  Please post a sample one that does not.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i mixed it up with c++ behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to print `new->DATA` value before you assign it's value. print it after assigning the value.

And `head` pointer is a local variable, so it's changes will not be reflected in `Main()` function. Change head pointer as follows inside `Convert()` function.

```
*head = NULL;
```

And your `Main()` function should be updated as follows,

```
int main(){
    int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    node* head;
    convert(arr, size, &head);
    return 0;
}
```

updated:

Change your `Convert()` function as follows,

```
void convert(int A[], int N, node ** head) {
  * head = NULL;
  while (N != -1) {
    node * new;
    new = malloc(sizeof new[0]);
    if (new == NULL) {
      printf("Memory not available");
      return;
    }
    new -> DATA = A[N - 1];
    printf("%i", new -> DATA);
    new -> LINK = * head;
    * head = new;
    N--;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether the `&head` is needed in this instance. My compiler would throw an error, otherwise. I think for this to work, I need a double pointer for the parameter.

Comment: @Emil11 Have you updated the head as follows inside the Convert function `*head = NULL;`

Comment: Sachith, `new = malloc(sizeof new[0]);` is  simpler and more direct than `new = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you very much, I'll update it

Comment: Notice that `new -> DATA = A[0 - 1];` is attempted.

Comment: Now it works better with the double pointer, although I do not think I need this version. It may be option I will opt for when experiencing errors regarding `segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem into smaller bits. Use functions to program them.

```
typedef struct node {
    int DATA;
    struct node* LINK;
} node;

node *add(node *last, int data)
{
    node *wrk = malloc(sizeof(*wrk));
    if(wrk)
    {
        wrk -> DATA = data;
        wrk -> LINK = NULL;
    }
    if(last) last -> LINK = wrk;
    else last = wrk;
    return wrk;
}

node *convert(int *data, size_t size)
{
    node *head = NULL, *last;
    
    if(data && size) 
    {
        if((head = add(NULL, *data++)))
        {
            last = head;
            while(--size)
            {
                if(!(last = add(last, *data++))) break;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void printList(const node *head)
{
    while(head)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head -> DATA);
        head = head -> LINK;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {9, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    node *head = convert(arr, size);

    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creative! will have to study your interpretation